# CQRS Event Sourcing valueobject & entities accepting commands

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

Experts,

I am in the evaluating moving a nice designed DDD app to an event sourced architecture as a pet project.

As can be inferred,  my Aggregate operations are relatively coarse grained. As part of my design process, I now find myself emitting a large number of events from a small subset of operations to satisfy what I know to be requirements of the read model.    Is this acceptable practice ?

In addition to this, I have distilled a lot of the domain complexity via use of ValueObjects & entities. Can VO's/ E accept commands and emit events themselves,  or should I expose state and add from the command handler lower down the stack ?

In terms of VO's note that I use mutable operations sparingly and it is a trade off between over complicating other areas of my domain.

Answer (score 0):

> I now find myself emitting a large number of events from a small subset of operations to satisfy what I know to be requirements of the read model. Is this acceptable practice ?

In most cases, you should have 1 event by command. Remember events describe the user intent so you have to stay close to the user action.

> Can VO's/ E accept commands and emit events themselves

No only aggregates emit events and yes you can come up with very messy aggregates if you have a lot of events, but there is solutions for that like delegating the work to the commands and events themselves. I blogged about this technique here: https://dev.to/maximegel/cqrs-scalable-aggregates-731

> In terms of VO's note that I use mutable operations sparingly

As long as you're aware of the consequences. That's fine. Trade-off are part of the job, but be sure you team is aware of that since it's written everywhere that value objects are immutable you expose yourselves to confusion and pointer issues.